# ASCII NULL character

Tags: ascii

ASCII is only for character. **NULL** is not a character, then why **NULL** has a ASCII value 0

Comment: You could not implement null-terminated strings without NUL. Its use in that context is as a *sentinel* value.

Answer (score 20):

> ASCII is only for [printable] character[s]

Not quite: in addition to *printable* characters, ASCII also includes a number of *control* characters.

ASCII code 0 (NUL) is one such control character.

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters):

> ASCII reserves the first 32 codes (numbers 0-31 decimal) for control characters: codes originally intended not to represent printable information, but rather to control devices (such as printers) that make use of ASCII, or to provide meta-information about data streams such as those stored on magnetic tape. For example, character 10 represents the "line feed" function (which causes a printer to advance its paper), and character 8 represents "backspace".

These days, the NUL character is most frequently used to signify the end of a character string in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29). Its original purpose, however, [was different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character):

> The original meaning of this character was like NOP -- when sent to a printer or a terminal, it does nothing (some terminals, however, incorrectly display it as space). When electromechanical teleprinters were used as computer output devices, one or more null characters were sent at the end of each printed line to allow time for the mechanism to return to the first printing position on the next line. On punched tape, the character is represented with no holes at all, so a new unpunched tape is initially filled with null characters, and often text could be "inserted" at a reserved space of null characters by punching the new characters into the tape over the nulls.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting your point properly.