# ncurses form: set_field_pad with no pad

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, screen, ncurses

In Linux `ncurses` and with the C language, using the `form.h` library it is possible to specify which pad character should be printed on screen in the empty positions of a certain field. That is: if a field is only partially filled by some characters typed by the user, the remaining ones will be momentarily equal to the specified pad character.

The function is

```
set_field_pad(FIELD *field, int pad)
```

As stated [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO) (sec. 18.3.4), the default pad character is a blank space. First of all: if I choose to change it to `@`, not only a `@` will be showed in the empty characters, but also where I type <kbd>space</kbd>. Is this avoidable? <kbd>space</kbd> is a character that I intentionally typed, while the empty characters are where I never typed anything.

I tried calling `set_field_pad` with several values for `int pad`, in particular `0` and `3` (ASCII values for `NULL` and End of Text) but the resulting pad character has always remained "space" as in the default case. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532514/ascii-null-character) it is said that some terminal incorrectly display `NULL` as a blank space.

I would like to have **no** padding character: the cursor in the field should **stop** on the last character typed by the user. If it was possible, how could I set this for my field?

Comment: Could you please clarify what behavior of example 26 in the manual you would like to change?  Is turning the `O_STATIC` option off what you want?

Comment: @Lorehead I was not explicitly referring to Example 26. What I would like to obtain is: given a field of a fixed length, when the user begins to fill it with some characters, the remaining characters of the field are **not accessible** and not some simple spaces as in the default behaviour! That is: if in a field of 100 characters the user types just `hello` in the beginning, the cursor will wait for input at the right of the `o` and if the user presses the right arrow the cursor **doesn't move** right. As default instead the cursor is free to move all over the field.

Comment: @Lorehead I don't know if `O_STATIC` provides exactly this: it is for variable length fields. Do you suggest to try it anyway?

Comment: It would take some work, but you could do what you are asking by supplying the field-validation logic in your program, and using that to prevent some of the requests which would be routed to `form_driver` (and no, I haven't time to write a lengthy example -- have a nice day).

Comment: emit padding space in field-validation is horrible in some case ( such as password input. unless your policy forbidden space in password.)   still finding a way to set no-pad.